# How to Replace Values in Pandas Rows with Ranks

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, each of which has their own value.

```
data = {'name' : ['bill', 'joe', 'steve'],
    'test1' : [7, 75, 85],
    'test2' : [35, 45, 83],
     'test3' : [51, 61, 45]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    name  test1  test2  test3
0   bill      7     35     51
1    joe     75     45     61
2  steve     85     83     45
```

I would like to replace the values in some of the columns with relative rank across the row rather than actual value. The output would be as follows.

```
    name  test1  test2  test3
0   bill      3     2      1
1    joe      1     3      2
2  steve      1     2      3
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Where do you get the relative values from? In your example they don't seem to be consistent. UPD: I got it, the lower value gets 3 and the higher value gets 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.rank` on axis 1

```
df = df.assign(**df.iloc[:, 1:].rank(axis = 1, ascending = False).astype(int))

    name    test1   test2   test3
0   bill    3       2       1
1   joe     1       3       2
2   steve   1       2       3
```

Comment: I love the double splat (-:

Answer (score 3):

#### Mind-Bending Numpy Assignment

```
a = np.argsort(df.iloc[:, 1:].to_numpy(), axis=1)
n, m = a.shape
b = np.empty_like(a)
c, d = np.mgrid[:n, :m]
b[c, a] = m - d

df.iloc[:, 1:] = b

df

    name  test1  test2  test3
0   bill      3      2      1
1    joe      1      3      2
2  steve      1      2      3
```

Comment: This is actually a better answer than the accepted answer because it even deals with cases  in which several values share the same rank.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> df.rank("columns", ascending=False)
   test1  test2  test3
0    3.0    2.0    1.0
1    1.0    3.0    2.0
2    1.0    2.0    3.0

>>> rankcols = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
>>> df[rankcols] = df[rankcols].rank("columns", ascending=False).astype(int)
>>> df
    name  test1  test2  test3
0   bill      3      2      1
1    joe      1      3      2
2  steve      1      2      3
```